# Post params to facebook wall with android

Tags: java, android, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Im trying to post to facebook with the facebook sdk, I set up my parameters in the dialog box but they do not show up when I go to post... any help? Facebook says pass the parameters name and description which I do... but nothing is showing up..

```
public void postToWall(View v){

 Bundle parameters = new Bundle();    
  parameters.putString("name", "My App test");
  parameters.putString("description", "This is a test");


  facebook.dialog(this, "feed", parameters, new     
    DialogListener() {

    @Override
    public void onFacebookError(FacebookError e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onError(DialogError e) {
    }

    @Override
    public void onComplete(Bundle values) {





    }

    @Override
    public void onCancel() {
    }
});
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "name" and "description" are only applicable if you also have a "link" parameter (which is a url string).

Here's the doc for the feed dialog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

For "name": "The name of the link attachment."

For "description: "The description of the link..."

Comment: Thanks! I cant believe it was something so simple I left out.

Comment: sorry but could you tell me where can i get that link?

Comment: @MingLi Let's say I do not have a link. Am I still able to put up the dotted line box with some text and picture?

Comment: No, that preview is only for shares with a link.